# How do I resize the Math Input Panel?

Tags: windows-7, math-input-panel

[image]

Is it possible to resize the Windows 7 Math Input Panel? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Math Input Panel auto re-sizes when you are near any of the edges.  There is no way to pre-re-size it.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can't resize the Math Input Panel.

If you click on **Close** button, it will go and reside on task bar icons.